# Why does my iPhone app show that it requires cellular data capability (entitlement) in the settings app

Tags: ios, iphone

My app does not require "Cellular data" yet my app is included in the App setting section and there is a configuration to allow the App to access "Cellular data". Why is that? How do I get it to not require that setting?

Note that there is no "cellular data" capability in xcode. I checked the plist and did not see anything.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You're just asking how iOS 9 behaves.

Comment: Well I assume there is a setting I can change or something I can do? My app does not use the cell network although it uses the local LAN.

Comment: "My app does not use the cell network" Well, I presume that that fact is not magically evident. You use the network, so you _might_ in theory use the cell; networking calls _do_ have the potential to fall back on using the cell by default, so how do we know you don't do that? I repeat; this is just how the iOS interface works. If you don't like it, file a bug with Apple.

Comment: Well what about if your app doesn't make any network calls? I'm in the same situation, except I don't use any networking calls in my app. Is it just required to have that setting for all apps? @matt

Answer (score 0):

It isn't about allowing but about preventing. If your app were to communicate over the network, the user needs a way to prevent that communication from using the cell (so as not to exceed cell data limits). This is how an iOS device allows the user to do that.

Comment: BTW - this has been around since iOS 8.